# C# lambda expression return value

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a lambda expression and I would like to get back the matched value.  Here is an example:

```
if (Keywords.Any(s => sourceString.Contains(" " + s.Trim())))
          return s;
```

Comment: you can use [First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb535050(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you only want the *first* matched result (given you are using `Any`), you can use [First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb535050(v=vs.100).aspx) / [FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549039(v=vs.100).aspx) with a filter. Given there is a chance that there could be no matches, I would recommend using `FirstOrDefault` (`First` would throw an exception in that case).

```
var matched = Keywords.FirstOrDefault(s => sourceString.Contains(" " + s.Trim()));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Keywords.First(s => sourceString.Contains(" " + s.Trim()))
```

Take a look to Single, SingleOrDefault, First or FirstOrDefault extension methods, depending by the behavior you want.

If you want to get the collection of matching items:

```
Keywords.Where(s => sourceString.Contains(" " + s.Trim())).ToList()
```

Comment: Well you wouldn't want `Single` / `SingleOrDefault` here because there is a chance there could be duplicate entries.

Comment: Correct! In fact i wrote my example with "First"... but not knowing the start collection i've exposed all the similar methods ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.First` or `.FirstOrDefault` for this.

But `.First` will throw an Exception if nothing is found.

```
var s = Keywords.FirstOrDefault(keyword => sourceString.Contains(" " + keyword .Trim())); 
return s;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
return Keywords.FirstOrDefault(s => sourceString.Contains(" " + s.Trim()));
```

This returns the match if found and `null` if it wasn't found.

Beware of doing this against a database though - `.Contains` will likely translate to an inefficient query using `LIKE`. Investigate full-text indexing if that's the case.

Comment: In most cases, `Contains` won't even be supported by the provider.